SCFT without $R$-symmetry
Suppose that there is SQCD, with adjoint chiral superfield $X$ and superpotential $W$ which is given as
$$W = Tr (X^2+X^3)$$
Then $Tr X^3$ term vanishes in the fixed point.
In this situation, I have two question.

why this term is irrelevant?

Is there $R$-symmetry in the fixed point?


